# convert java to scala code - change of method signatures

Tags: java, scala, overloading, raw-types

Trying to convert some java to scala code I face the problem of a different method signature which compiled fine in the java world:

The following code in java (from https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/master/babylon/src/main/java/org/datasyslab/babylon/showcase/Example.java#L122-L126)

```
visualizationOperator = new ScatterPlot(1000,600,USMainLandBoundary,false,-1,-1,true,true);
visualizationOperator.CustomizeColor(255, 255, 255, 255, Color.GREEN, true);
visualizationOperator.Visualize(sparkContext, spatialRDD);
imageGenerator = new SparkImageGenerator();
imageGenerator.SaveAsFile(visualizationOperator.distributedVectorImage, "file://"+outputPath,ImageType.SVG);
```

Is translated to https://github.com/geoHeil/geoSparkScalaSample/blob/master/src/main/scala/myOrg/visualization/Vis.scala#L45-L57

```
val vDistributedVector = new ScatterPlot(1000, 600, USMainLandBoundary, false, -1, -1, true, true)
vDistributedVector.CustomizeColor(255, 255, 255, 255, Color.GREEN, true)
vDistributedVector.Visualize(s, spatialRDD)
sparkImageGenerator.SaveAsFile(vDistributedVector.distributedVectorImage, outputPath + "distributedVector", ImageType.SVG)
```

Which will throw the following error:

```
overloaded method value SaveAsFile with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: java.util.List[String],x$2: String,x$3: org.datasyslab.babylon.utils.ImageType)Boolean <and>
[error]   (x$1: java.awt.image.BufferedImage,x$2: String,x$3: org.datasyslab.babylon.utils.ImageType)Boolean <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD,x$2: String,x$3: org.datasyslab.babylon.utils.ImageType)Boolean
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD[Integer,String], String, org.datasyslab.babylon.utils.ImageType)
[error]     sparkImageGenerator.SaveAsFile(vDistributedVector.distributedVectorImage, outputPath + "distributedVector", ImageType.SVG)
```

Unfortunately, I am not really sure how to fix this / how to properly call the method in scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem in `ImageGenerator`, inherited by `SparkImageGenerator`. As you can see [here](https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/f5aabdb05d1ef08b17b9774af654199c2ac9933a/babylon/src/main/java/org/datasyslab/babylon/core/ImageGenerator.java), it has a method

```
public boolean SaveAsFile(JavaPairRDD distributedImage, String outputPath, ImageType imageType)
```

which uses a raw type (`JavaPairRDD` without `<...>`). They exist primarily for compatibility with pre-Java 5 code and [shouldn't normally be used otherwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). For this code, there is certainly no good reason, as it actually expects specific type parameters. Using raw types merely loses type-safety. Maybe some subclasses (current or potential) might override it and expect *different* type parameters, but this would be a misuse of inheritance and there must be a better solution.

<s>Scala doesn't support raw types in any way and so you can't call this method from it (AFAIK). As a workaround, you could write a wrapper in Java which used correct types and call this wrapper from Scala.</s> I misremembered, it's extending Java classes extending raw types which was impossible, and even then there are workarounds.

You might be able to call it by explicit type ascription (preferable to casting):

```
sparkImageGenerator.SaveAsFile(
  (vDistributedVector.distributedVectorImage: JavaPairRDD[_, _]), 
  outputPath + "distributedVector", ImageType.SVG)
```

But given the error message shows just `JavaPairRDD`, I don't particularly expect it to work. If this fails, I'd still go with a Java wrapper.

Comment: I thought raw types are interpreted as existential types in Scala.

Comment: Ugh, you are right, of course. The problem is that in this specific case it doesn't seem to interpret it this way, because the error message shows it as a raw type (`x$1: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD,...`).

Comment: I'm not sure though if that's a problem with the error message or with the typechecker. I actually have a pull request going to improve some error messages about raw types: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5847

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct in saying that raw types should be avoided. However Scala *can* interoperate with Java code that has raw types. Scala interprets the raw type `java.util.List` as the existential type `java.util.List[_]`.

Take for example this Java code:

```
// Test.java
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
  public boolean foo(Map map, String s) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then try to call it from Scala:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.util.{Map,HashMap}
import java.util.{Map,HashMap}

scala> new Test().foo(new HashMap[String,Integer], "a")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> val h: Map[_,_] = new HashMap[String,Integer]
h: java.util.Map[_, _] = {}

scala> new Test().foo(h, "a")
res1: Boolean = true
```

So it looks like there must be some other problem.