# Convert java to scala - overloaded static methods

Tags: java, scala, static-methods, overloading

I have java code like compiles fine.

```
import org.jaitools.numeric.Range;
Range<Integer> r1 = Range.create(1, true, 4, true);
```

Converted to Scala like

```
val r1: org.jaitools.numeric.Range[Integer] = org.jaitools.numeric.Range.create(1, true, 4, true)
```

compilation fails as java seems to go for this method:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable> Range<T> create(T minValue, boolean minIncluded, T maxValue, boolean maxIncluded) {
        return new Range<T>(minValue, minIncluded, maxValue, maxIncluded);
    }
```

whereas the Scala compiler will choose to use

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable> Range<T> create(T value, int... inf) {
        return new Range<T>(value, inf);
}
```

i.e. the type arguments do not match.

Both are overloaded methods in the same class.
How can I get the Scala compiler to choose the right method?

## edit

```
val r1: org.jaitools.numeric.Range[Integer] = org.jaitools.numeric.Range.create(1, true, 4, true)
```

results in

```
overloaded method value create with alternatives:
  [T <: Number with Comparable[_]](x$1: T, x$2: Int*)org.jaitools.numeric.Range[T] <and>
  [T <: Number with Comparable[_]](x$1: T, x$2: Boolean, x$3: T, x$4: Boolean)org.jaitools.numeric.Range[T]
 cannot be applied to (Int, Boolean, Int, Boolean)
       val r1: org.jaitools.numeric.Range[Integer] = org.jaitools.numeric.Range.create(1, true, 4, true)
```

Maybe this is also a case of [convert java to scala code - change of method signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626048/convert-java-to-scala-code-change-of-method-signatures) where the type system of java and Scala do not work well together?

Comment: I am not familiar with this specific package but this seems to be an issue of converting types. try to do Range.create(int2Int(1), true, int2Int(4), true);

Comment: Which method are you referring to with `int2Int `?

Comment: Note that you are using Range[Integer] which refers to java.util.Integer, however in scala 1 and 4 are Int. scala predef includes a function int2Int to do the conversion. While this generally happens automatically, it can fail in certain situations. This could be one of them

Comment: In the scala gitter I was told to try `org.jaitools.numeric.Range.create(Integer.valueOf(1), true, Integer.valueOf(4), true)` i.e. to use manual boxing. This works fine.

Comment: It is similar logic. Another option which **MIGHT** work (but probably wont) is to use org.jaitools.numeric.Range[Int]

Comment: I tried your last suggestion already - could not get that to compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145730/discussion-between-assaf-mendelson-and-georg-heiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `Int` and `java.lang.Integer` are two different things. `create` expects its first and third parameters to be of the same type as the type parameter. You are specifying the param as `Integer` but arguments you are passing in - 1 and 4 - are of type `Int`.

You cannot create `Range[Int]`, because the type parameter is required to extend `Number` and `Comparable`, which `Int` does not. So, you have to wrap your `Int`s into `Integer` explicitly

```
val r1 = org.jaitools.numeric.Range.create(Integer.valueOf(1), true, Integer.valueOf(4), true)
```